# HttpClient.Post forbidden from IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a C# / WCF service which needs to process a post request to a third party company. It sends documents to this outsourcing company. The C# code, use a HttpClient.PostAsync and works without any problems on Visual Studio 2013 with IIS Express. I deployed a self hosted WCF service on my server and it still works ! But, when I deploy this code on IIS (on the same server), I have the following exception : `System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Forbidden`.

Here are exception details :

```
HTTP Code [Forbidden] 
Phrase="Forbidden" 
Message="Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://third.party.company/api/sandbox//users/73437a40-3827-4df6-855f-c58c00750007', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/vnd.v1+json
  Authorization: Bearer *****
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="ec9e6a56-103a-4728-a152-d86e836fe62e"
  Content-Length: 138986
}" Result = [<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /api/sandbox//users/73437a40-3827-4df6-855f-c58c00750007
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
]
```

There can be two problems :

- The post request is too big
- There is an **hidden** setting in IIS which blocks the request

The server runs under Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5

Can you help me ?

Many Thanks !

Comment: have you got authentication enabled?

Comment: No. WebDeploy is enabled by authentication but the "site" allow anonymous access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the two slash in the post URL :

```
https://third.party.company/api/sandbox//users/73437a40-3827-4df6-855f-c58c00750007
```

I works whitout problems with only one.

I do not understand, why there is no error on IIS logs and why the url is truncated before `api` instead of `users`